# Spring Boot - Security/JPA - Insert to the database when getting a response from the handler

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I want to insert a successful or failed login to the database depending on whether the user entered their credentials correctly or not.

If the user enters their credentials incorrectly, the **failureHandler** should call the service and insert the failed login record into the database with the IP Address of the user trying to log in, the session type, and the date, but when testing my code it shows me the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.user.service.SessionService.errorSession(String)" because "this.service" is null
at cpggsp.sopp.config.AuthenticationFailureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(AuthenticationFailureHandler.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.unsuccessfulAuthentication(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:354) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:249) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
```

The same process has to do with the **successHandler**, but I get the same error.

Here my code

**WebSecurityConfiguration:**

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(
            "/login**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .permitAll();

    return httpSecurity.build();
}

@Autowired
private AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
```

**AuthenticationFailureHandler:**

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler  {
    
    private SessionService service;
    
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("A user has falied to login. Error: " + exception.getMessage());
        
        String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();

        service.errorSession(ipAddress);
        
        super.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?error");
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
        
    }

}
```

**AuthenticationSuccessHandler:**

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    
    private SessionService service;
    
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("The user " + authentication.getName() + " is logged in successfully");
        
        String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();

        service.loginSession(ipAddress);
        
        super.setDefaultTargetUrl("/home");
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        
    }

}
```

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sessions")
public class Session {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_session")
    private Long idSession;
    
    @Column(name = "ip_address", nullable = false)
    private String ipAddress;
    
    @Column(name = "session", nullable = false)
    private String Session;
    
    @Column(name = "date_session", nullable = false)
    private String  dateSession;

    public Session() {
    }

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

**SessionRepository:**

```
public interface SessionRepositorio extends JpaRepository<Session, Long> {
    
    @Query(nativeQuery= true, value="INSERT INTO sessions(ip_address, session, date_session) "
            + "VALUES(:ipAddress, 'Log In Success', NOW())")
    public void loginSession(String ipAddress);
    
    @Query(nativeQuery= true, value="INSERT INTO sessions(ip_address, session, date_session) "
            + "VALUES(:ipAddress, 'Log In Failed', NOW())")
    public void errorSession(String ipAddress);
    
}
```

**SessionService:**

```
@Service
public class SessionService {

    @Autowired
    private SessionRepositorio sessionRepository;
    
    public void loginSession(String ipAddress) {
        sessionRepository.loginSession(ipAddress);
    }
    
    public void errorSession(String ipAddress) {
        sessionRepository.errorSession(ipAddress);
    }

}
```

The IDE does not show me an error in my code, it only shows me that error when I run the project and log in by entering the credentials incorrectly or successfully, in addition to not registering any new records in the database.

Any suggestions or solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was something simple I had to add `@Autowired` to **AuthenticationFailureHandler** and also to **AuthenticationSuccessHandler** and now it accomplishes the task.

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler  {
    
    @Autowired
    private SessionService service;
    
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("A user has falied to login. Error: " + exception.getMessage());
        
        String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
        
        service.errorSession(ipAddress);
        
        super.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?error");
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
        
    }

}
```